# quiz code needs to be converted into text

Tags: binary, hex

I was going to apply for an engineers job then they threw this quiz at me below. I can convert the binary code OK and I assume the rest is hex code. But every time I try to convert the hex code I dont get an anwser? The Binary reads as visit .....co.no  I'm not a programmer just install servers so if any one can work out what the quiz says would be much appreciated.

01110110 01101001 01110011 01101001 01110100
74 68 65
77 65 62 73 69 74 65
3262d48df5d75e3452f0f16b313b7808
8fc42c6ddf9966db3b09e84365034357
5f3f4681121b460e3304a1887f42f1c3
00101110 01100011 01101111 00101110 01101110 01111010
66 6f 72 20 6d 6f 72 65 20 64 65 74 61 69 6c 73

Answer (score 0):

**Binary** - 01110110 01101001 01110011 01101001 01110100

visit

**Hex** - 74 68 65 77 65 62 73 69 74 65

thewebsite

**md5** - 3262d48df5d75e3452f0f16b313b7808

off

**md5** - 8fc42c6ddf9966db3b09e84365034357

the

**md5** - 5f3f4681121b460e3304a1887f42f1c3

bat

**binary** - 00101110 01100011 01101111 00101110 01101110 01111010

.co.nz

**hex** - 66 6f 72 20 6d 6f 72 65 20 64 65 74 61 69 6c 73

for more details

Comment: Normally I wouldn't answer questions like this, but I visited the website and it's 404'd. So either it's already down or finding the website was only the first step.